# Itinerary webapp for bicycles, usable in Tokyo

Tags: gratis, web-apps, itinerary

I want a webapp that tells me what is the best itinerary between two points for a bicycle.

Google Maps has a "Bicycle" button but it does not work in Tokyo.

Requirements:

- Free to use
- Avoids stairs and highways
- Works for routes within Tokyo

Would be great:

- Takes slopes into accounts
- Shows time estimate (for an average rider, or letting users choose their strength)